# Grid Layout of View in React Native

Tags: android, css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I am trying to create a React Native View with a Layout like this one. How can I create a box, like one of the boxes on the image?

Is it possible to achieve this with Flex? I need one  for the number (left), one for a text (right, top) and for another text (right, bottom)? They should be in the same order like on the image.

Comment: Give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: Flex should do the trick for the number and the text container. Then, the text container can hold both `text` as normal `block`

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to learn flexbox styling rules.

It will make your life easier to design such simple screens.

Your render method should look something like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
            <Text style={styles.numberStyle}>6</Text>
            <View style={styles.textContainerStyle}>
                <Text>D in 227 -</Text>
                <Text>Vtr. Online Lehrer</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Your styles should look like this:

```
const styles = {
    containerStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'space-around'
    },
    numberStyle: {
        flex: 1
    },
    textContainerStyle: {
        flex: 4,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center' 
    }
}
```

**Note:** I have not tested the output, but it should work. If it is not working as expected then please feel free to ask me.

You can learn flexbox here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

The above link is for css but still if you learn that then you can apply similarly in React Native.

Answer (score 0):

There are two properties you need to be aware of to get your text to align in the center of the view.

The first is justifyContent and the second is alignItems. You need to use these properties in your styling object to get the text tag to move to the center of the view.

You have to do something like `justifyContent: 'flex-end'`. Usually this is used for the vertical position. We can give `justifyContent` `'flex-end'` to push your text box all the way down. `'center'` will of course place your text box in the middle.

There is also `justifyContent:'flex-start'`. This is as if you provided no property at all, so no need to use this one.

The second property is `alignItems` for whose values are the same as `justifyContent`. So `justifyContent` is for vertical alginment and `alignItems` is for horizontal alignment.

So it would look something like this:

```
// Import a library to help create a component
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

// Make a component
const Header = (props) => {
  const { textStyle, viewStyle } = styles;

  return (
    <View style={viewStyle}>
      <Text style={textStyle}>{props.headerText}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = {
  viewStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 60
  },
  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 20
  }
};

// Make the component available to other parts of the app
export default Header;
```